# Java give a class as parametre

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

How can I give a class as a parametre in a method that I can then make one like that:

```
Type obj = new Type();
```

is that possible?

Comment: Use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

`MyClass.class`

Let's say you have this method:

`private void doSomething(Class cls) {}`

you'd call with

`doSomething(MyClass.cls);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it different ways.

1. Pass a string parameter with full ClassName:

   ```
   void someMethod(String className) {    // className like "com.mypackage.Type"
       Type obj = (Type)Class.forName(className).newInstance();    
   }
   ```
2. Pass a Class type:

   ```
   void someMethod(Class clazz) {    // clazz is Type.class
       clazz.newInstance();
   }
   ```